# Do something, return or continue, PHP one-liner syntax

Tags: php, syntax

I am looking for a one-liner PHP syntax that would allow me to do this:

```
function printMsg($do_print, $msg) {
    if ($do_print) {
        echo "$msg\n";
    }
    return $do_print;
}

function test() {
    printMsg(false, 'foo') and return;   <== need a one liner for this
    printMsg(true, 'bar') and return;
}

echo "before"; // before
test();        // bar
echo "after";  // after
```

So far the best I have is to do:

```
if (printMsg(false, 'foo')) return;
```

The problem is that upon reformatting my code my IDE ([NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans)) puts it on two lines. It's not dramatic, but I have a piece of code with many calls like this, and having a one-liner that stays on one line would make it much more concise/readable.

Are there any other one-line syntaxes possible in PHP for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Let'S discuss your metaproblem! You do not have the problem that a certain command has to stay on one line. You more likely have a problem of how to express what you really want to do - and that is what I didn't understand from your current statements. I'm like 'WTF, if you know you don't want to output and return, then do not call anything in the first line of your `test()` function.'

Comment: so basically you want something like `return(2)` to return 2 levels up the call stack, rather than than the usual 1?

Comment: Yes that's it. I was just completely unaware that I could do that, so I came up with that one-liner alternative.

Comment: @MarcB: I seem to be having problems doing the same thing from within a class, is that normal?

Comment: that was just hypothetical syntax. return can return a single value up to the parent/calling scope. there's no option to return multiple levels.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
function printMsg($msg, $print = false) {
    $print and print("$msg\n");
    return $print;
}

function test($r = null) {
    printMsg('foo') and $r = false;
    printMsg('bar', true) and $r = true;
    return $r;
}

echo "<pre>";
echo "before\n"; // before
test(); // bar
echo "after\n"; // after
```

Output

```
before
bar
after
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly, but I should be able to continue the execution inside the function if needed. In my example if I set `printMsg(false, 'bar')`, it continues executing what's in `test()` (granted there is nothing in the example). In the code you provided, even if I do `printMsg('bar',false)` I will exit the function no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you should be able to accomplish this with:

```
function test() {
    printMsg(false, 'foo') || printMsg(true, 'bar');
}
```

Here, if the first `printMsg()` returns true, the second `printMsg()` will not be executed. If it returns false, the second `printMsg()` will be executed.

Example:

```
printMsg(false, 'foo') || printMsg(true, 'bar'); // bar
printMsg(true, 'foo') || printMsg(true, 'bar'); // foo
printMsg(false, 'foo') || printMsg(false, 'bar') || printMsg(true, 'ok'); // ok
```

However, whitespace doesn't cost anything and this code is far from readable. In six months, you'll have to think for a moment to figure out what it does, and anyone coming after you isn't likely to understand it at first glance.

I would strongly recommend you split the code onto a couple of lines and just use an `if` statement.